# PHPMailer wont work?

Tags: php, email

So I put all the files in and change the SMTP information but for some reason, I can not get it to work. Here is what the PHP looks like..

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'MYEMAILADDRESS';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'MYEMAILPASSWORD';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
?>
```

And I get this error when opening the page.

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Please help!

Comment: trying to connect with yahoo itself? or any other server?

Comment: I do not see what u r asking.

Comment: can you ping smtp.mail.yahoo.com?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you're using TLS SMTPSecure.

Try to set your smtp port to 587 or 465.

```
$mail->Port = 465; //SSL
$mail->Port = 587; //TLS
```

By the way, try to ping your smtp server or execute a telnet trying each port (587 or 465), maybe there is a proxy blocking your connection through that ports.

Answer (score 0):

For $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
try $mail->Port = 587;